# How can I animate a rectangle with a sine like motion and rotation?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to animate a rectangle in a sine like wave motion. I want it to go up and down like a sine wave, but I also want the rectangle to rotate so the "front" of the rectangle is facing the direction of up/down movement.

So when the wave is moving up, I want the rectangle to tilt counterclock wise and then tilt clockwise when moving down.

I just can't seem to get the correct degrees or translations down. Could anyone help?

Here's my fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rneLy8g1/1/)

This is what I currently have

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0%{transform: rotate(10deg) translateY(-50px)}
  50%{transform: rotate(-10deg) translateY(50px)}
  100%{transform: rotate(10deg) translateY(-50px)}
} 
.rectangle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 15% auto;
  animation: rotate 3s infinite ease-in-out; 
}
```

Comment: You would need a bezier curve function fot the timing.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function

Answer (score 0):

Here, let me know if this works for you:

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0%{transform:translateY(50px)}
  25%{transform:translateY(0px) rotate(-10deg) }
  75%{transform:translateY(0px) rotate(10deg)  }
  100%{transform:translateY(50px) }
} 

.rectangle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 15% auto;
  animation: rotate 3s infinite ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: It's definitely a start. Still looking for it to be a little smoother if possible. So I'll play around with going from you've posted.